# React-native-webrtc, how to end a call properly?

Tags: react-native, audio, webrtc

I work with webrtc on react-native.
When a user enters in room I need him to join the audio conversation.
Everything works fine the first time, but when he returns to the same room and leaves it,
peer audio does not turn off, and we still hear it in the app.
I don't find out why.
I don't know if it's my way of quitting room, or my complete code that's bad.
If you have an idea to help me I am interested, here is my complete code for the audio connection.

Thanks for reading me!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';

class WebRTC extends Component {
  pc_config = {
    iceServers: ****
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pcPeers = {};
    this.state = {
      localStream: '',
      remoteList: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getLocalStream();

    this.props.socket.on('leave', (idLeave) => {
      this.leave(idLeave);
    });
    this.props.socket.on('exchange', (data) => {
      this.exchange(data);
    });
    this.props.socket.on('mute', (data) => {
      this.muteMic(data.val);
    });
    this.props.socket.on('closeRtc', () => {
      this.closeRtc();
    });
  }

  stopTracks = (stream) => {
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
  }

  closeRtc = async() => {
    if (this.state.localStream != null) {
      this.stopTracks(this.state.localStream);
      this.state.localStream.release();
    }

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.remoteList)) {
      await value.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.pcPeers)) {
      await value.close();
    }
  
    this.setState({
      remoteList: {},
      localStream: '',
    });
    this.pcPeers = {};
    
    this.props.socket.emit("leaveRtc", {room: GLOBAL.ROOM_NAME});
    this.props.socket.off();
    this.props.socket.close();
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      key: null,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Main'})],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }

  getLocalStream = () => {
    mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: false,
    }).then(async stream => {
      this.join();
      this.setState({
        localStream: stream,
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('error => ', error);
    });
  };

  join = async () => {
    let callback = (socketIds) => {
      Object.keys(socketIds).forEach(index => {
        this.createPC(socketIds[index], true);
      });
    };
    this.props.socket.emit("ready", {room: GLOBAL.ROOM_NAME, socketID: this.props.socket.id}, callback);
  };

  exchange = data => {
    const fromId = data.from;
    let pc;
    if (fromId in this.pcPeers) {
      pc = this.pcPeers[fromId];
    } else {
      pc = this.createPC(fromId, false);
    }

    if (data.sdp) {
      let sdp = new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp);
      pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp).then(() =>
        pc.remoteDescription.type === 'offer' ? 
          pc.createAnswer()
            .then(desc =>
              pc
                .setLocalDescription(desc)
                .then(() =>
                  this.props.socket.emit('exchange', {
                    to: fromId,
                    sdp: pc.localDescription,
                    room: GLOBAL.ROOM_NAME,
                  }),
                ),
            )
          : null,
      );
    } else {
      pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
    }
  };

  leave = (idLeave) => {
    if (idLeave in this.pcPeers) {
      const tracks = this.state.remoteList[idLeave].getTracks();
      var pc = this.pcPeers[idLeave];

      tracks.forEach(function(track) {
        track.stop();
      });
      if (pc) {
        pc.close();
      }
      delete this.pcPeers[idLeave];
      delete this.state.remoteList[idLeave];
    }
  };

  createPC = (socketId, isOffer) => {
    const peer = new RTCPeerConnection(this.pc_config);
    this.pcPeers = {
      ...this.pcPeers,
      [socketId]: peer,
    };

    peer.addStream(this.state.localStream);

    peer.onicecandidate = event => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        this.props.socket.emit('exchange', {
          to: socketId,
          candidate: event.candidate,
          room: GLOBAL.ROOM_NAME,
        });
      }
    };

    peer.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
      if (isOffer) {
        createOffer();
      }
    };

    peer.onaddstream = event => {
      const remoteList = this.state.remoteList;
      remoteList[socketId] = event.stream;

      this.setState({remoteList});
    };

    const createOffer = () => {
      peer.createOffer().then(desc => {
        peer.setLocalDescription(desc).then(() => {
          this.props.socket.emit('exchange', {
            to: socketId,
            sdp: peer.localDescription,
            room: GLOBAL.ROOM_NAME,
          });
        });
      });
    };

    peer.close = () => {
        console.log("peer close");
    }

    return peer;
  };

  muteMic = async (val) => {
    if (this.state.localStream != null) {
      let audioTrack = this.state.localStream.getTracks().filter(track => track.kind === 'audio');
      audioTrack[0].enabled = val;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default WebRTC;
```

Comment: The socket may be disconnected and unable to receive the exit instruction

Comment: I try without socket.off and socket.close but same problem :/